# How to run an For Loop where if cell is true (has text), the row is copied to a different ss

Tags: excel, vba

So i want to make a loop where it checks the data in every cell in a column and if the cell has any type of data, it copy's the entire row to a different ss. If the cell is blank i need it to move onto the next cell below and not copy the row.

I have added some code below, im trying to copy all the rows in `report1` in column `H:H` that have any input to `Report3`.

```
Sub GenerateReport3_Click()

    Dim rep1 As Worksheet
    Dim rep3 As Worksheet

    Set rep1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report1")
    Set rep3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report3")

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    rep1.Range("A1:J1").Copy Destination:=rep3.Range("A1")

    Set rngA = Sheets("Report1").Range("H:H")
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = True Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=rep2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Every row in column in report 1 `H:H` that has any input needs to be copied to `Report3`.

Comment: `If cell.Value <> "" Then` instead of `If cell.Value = True Then` might work..

Comment: In if condition you are using `rep2` change `cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=rep3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)`

Comment: Perfect thanks Dean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for `Not IsEmpty(...)` rather than `=TRUE`.

Also, a few details around geting `Range` references need work (eg avoiding implicit references to `ActiveSheet`).

And don't loop over the entire 1,000,000+ rows in a column (That's *so* slow!)

Something like this

```
Sub GenerateReport3_Click()

    Dim rep1 As Worksheet
    Dim rep3 As Worksheet

    Set rep1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report1")
    Set rep3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report3")

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    rep1.Range("A1:J1").Copy Destination:=rep3.Cells(1, 1)

    With rep1 
        Set rngA = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In rngA
            If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=rep3.Cells(rep3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

<sub>Note that if this is still too slow, there a are more ways to speed it up</sub>